# Android StudioでRelativeLayoutの削除ができない

Tags: android, android-studio

LinearLayoutを使ったAndroidアプリを作るため、Blank Activityから作成したプロジェクトでデフォルトに設定されているRelativeLayoutを削除しようとしたところ、なぜか削除出来ませんでした。
なお、Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.9では削除出来ていたのですが、0.8.14にバージョンアップしたら出来なくなりました（開発環境はOS X 10.10）。
手作業でactivity_main.xmlを編集してLinearLayoutへの変更は出来ましたが、GUIから削除出来ない原因がわかる方がいれば教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

バグ修正の一環として、レイアウトエディタからは[トップにあるViewGroupを削除できなくなった](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76942#c2)ようです (バージョン0.8.13から)。この修正方法を採用した理由として、トップのViewGroupを削除するとビューツリーが不正な状態になるから、というのが挙げられています。

トップのViewGroupの種類を変更したい場合は「Morphing」メニューを利用せよ、とのことですが、すべての*Layout同士を相互に変換できるわけではないようです。(変換可能なクラスは[views-meta-model.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/com/intellij/android/designer/model/views-meta-model.xml#1370)で定義されている)。

メモ: この変更を見つけた手順:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea android-platform-tools-adt-idea
cd android-platform-tools-adt-idea
git log --grep layout # 上から順に関係ありそうなログを目視で探した
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。削除出来ないのは意図した仕様と言う事ですね。